# Arduino Mega Clone CH340G Capacitor Values

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, bootloader, resistor, capacitors

I'm making my own Arduino Mega board with ATmega2560-16AU and CH340G. Jump to the end of the post to find the real question.

I have already ordered a PCB before and it didn't work when I soldered everything in place. I have already asked why that board didn't work on another post here: [Programming custom Arduino Mega with Arduino Uno](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/81361/programming-custom-arduino-mega-with-arduino-uno)

But I was not satisfied with the answers and started suspecting whether or not the capacitor values were right on my board.

I'm trying to make my own version of RobotDyn's Arduino Mega 2560 Pro so I tried taking the already programmed ch340g and soldering it on my own board and still failed. When I put a previously not programmed ch340g on the RobotDyn board and programmed it using Arduino UNO (Arduino as ISP) the board would work.

So now I ordered a new PCB but haven't ordered any of the passive components yet.

**If any of you could tell me where I could find the values from the schematic below I would really appreciate that.**

https://robotdyn.com/pub/media/0G-00005641==MEGA-PRO-CH340GATmega2560/DOCS/Schematic==0G-00005641==MEGA-PRO-CH340GATmega2560.pdf

Comment: Most capacitors are decoupling capacitors, so 100nF. C1 is from the original Arduino schematic - also 100nF. As is C12. All the others depend on the components they are supporting - the load capacitance of the crystals, the required input and output capacitance for the voltage regulators, etc.

Comment: Just a dumb question, the processor chip is programmed with the bootloader?

Comment: @Majenko Oh yeah sorry forgot to tell about the regulators, I don't need the values for that but I believe I'm having trouble with CH340G capacitors.

Comment: @Dorian Uhhh.. yeah. I want to be able to program my Arduino via USB so I have CH340G there to translate the program to the MCU.

Comment: C3/4 are dependent on whatever crystal you're using. C2 is for the internal 3.3V regulator in the Ch340G. No idea what it *needs*, but probably 1uF is more than adequate.

Answer (score 2):

The values can be easy found for generic CH340g and ATmega2560 implementations:

C1,C2 = 100nF, C3,C4 = 22pf but depends on the crystal you use, all others excepting C12 are decoupling capacitors.

C12 has no sense where it's placed, it seems that the schematic is a bad combination of schematics, this capacitor should reset the board at power on but it breaks the reset pulse from CH340g so you cannot program the board without pressing manually the reset pushbutton. Don't place C12 at all.

Also place a short instead of R5 and R6 that are not in the CH340g manual (there is a special mention to connect the pins straight to USB bus), remove R8, is not needed for the same reason, R3 makes no sense, don't place-it.

R2,R4 = 1K, R7,R9 = 10K, R10,R11,R12,R13 = 1K, R14 = 10K , R15 = 1M.

Y1 = 12Mhz, Y2 = 16Mhz

A 22 ohm resistor is missing in your schematic between Y2 XTAL1 and ATMEGA XTAL2 but I don't think it's important.

I hope I didn't missed something

The bare minimum is to remove c12 and maybe R3 and check the values you used for R2, R4 against the above values.

If something would be wrong with CH340g the USB connection would fail but I see no mention about that in your post.

Comment: "C4 has no sense where it's placed".  I'm guessing you didn't mean C4 there, because you mention C4 above that point.  So, perhaps C5?.  But it is connected to AREF (for decoupling) rather than RESET.  Anyway, something for you to check.

Comment: @timemage you're right, sorry, it's C12. Fixed.

Comment: I think the  "all others excepting C4" may be caught up in that as well.  Referring to C12 as well?  Regarding C12, you can see it represented in [AVR042](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/Atmel-2521-AVR-Hardware-Design-Considerations_ApplicationNote_AVR042.pdf) figure 3-1, along with the reason for it a few paragraphs above.  That said, it's probably not needed here.

Comment: @timemage Yes, missed that to. Yes, it's a combination of some schematics,  in the AVR042 the reset line is not driven by another chip. The spike through C1 that should reset the chip to enter in botloader mode when programming is filtered by C12 and the programming fails.

Comment: Scratching my above comment.  You're right, it likely *is* counter-productive to have it there.  Before, I'd throught the pulse might make it through okay.  But, assuming two caps around equal value, the pulse will stop quite short of being adequate for reset.

Comment: @timemage  Not only short  but also half size because the pulse voltage will be divided between capacitors. At best would be 2.5V. As I know the Reset input has histeresis and needs more than half VDD to activate.

Comment: We're in violent agreement.